# Java2D Graphics Render Only Through OpenGL Pipeline

Tags: java, swing, opengl, direct3d, steam

TL;DR: Is there any way of forcing Java2D graphics to only go through the OpenGL pipeline, and entirely and completely ignore Direct3D and DirectDraw (desired effect: `opengl32.dll` should be used before `ddraw.dll`)?

I have created a game using Java and Swing with the intent of publishing on steam. A problem has arisen: the steam overlay doesn't appear. After asking in this [discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/17/1471967615882722653/) (not view-able for most people, keep reading for gist) the possible source of the problem was identified. The game is initializing Direct3D and DirectDraw before OpenGL, and the overlay is hooking on to the first of these, however OpenGL is the acceleration type supported by the steam overlay.

The problem would hopefully be fixed if Direct3D and DirectDraw are not used. That way the steam overlay will not try to hook on to them first, and just hook on to OpenGL.

I have tried the following flags to disable Direct3D and DirectDraw:
`-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` This has made no noticeable effect (`ddraw.dll` is still be used).

OpenGL is programmatically enabled because this is the only way the steam API can be initialize prior to the init of an OpenGL device:

```
//init steam api here. api init is required before OpenGL device init
System.out.println("The api was initialized successfully")
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");
//continue with the game initialization, creates a frame, game loop, callbacks, etc.
```

Console output:

```
The api was initialized successfully
OpenGL pipeline enabled for default config on screen 0
```

It is worth noting that JavaFX is also used in the game but purely for audio. Nothing graphical is initialized. I am not sure if this would cause a problem or conflict.

In summary:

I'm trying to use only the OpenGL pipeline for Java2D so that the steam overlay will hook on to the OpenGL device. `ddraw.dll` (direct draw) is being used just before `opengl32.dll` is used (making it so that the overlay tries and fails to hook on to `ddraw.dll` because it's being used first). I'm trying to get it not to use `ddraw.dll`, so that it will only try to hook on to `opengl32.dll`.

Side note: I'm not noticing any difference when using OpenGL versus standard Java2D. I'm getting the OpenGL pipeline enabled message (above), but is it possible that it's still not using it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the options you have used only apply to AWT and not JavaFX. So JavaFX could indeed be the problem here. As you are not using any JavaFX graphics anyway it might help to switch off the hardware acceleration of JavaFX via `-Dprism.order=sw`. To verify that you are actually not using it you could switch on logging too via `-Dprism.verbose=true`. I am not sure this helps but at least it is woth a try.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. `draw.dll` is still being used by something. I need to somehow figure out what is using it. Would it be reasonable to somehow delete `ddraw.dll`? That way whatever needs it will throw a stack trace, allowing me to trace it back and identify what is using it.